# Calling an API endpoint from a different API call

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm learning React, and playing around with https://pokeapi.co/

I am using axios to get a list of 20 Pokemon: `axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')`

This returns an array of objects. Each object has a Pokemon's name, and the API endpoint for more detail on that specific Pokemon.

I want to do the following:

1. Get the list of 20 Pokemon
2. Iterate through the array and call each Pokemon detail endpoint

I have this code, which is working, but seems not ideal because I'm getting into what I believe is referred to as "callback hell":

```
const [characters, setCharacters] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect( () => {
    // make axios call for list of pokemon

    axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
      .then( result => {
        result.data.results.forEach( character =>
          axios.get(character.url)
              .then( result => 
                setCharacters(
                  // add the pokemon object to the characters array
                    characters => [...characters, result.data])
                )
              )
              .catch( error => console.error(error));
      })
      .catch( error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);
```

I've been looking at `Promise.all()`/`axios.all()` but I'm a bit confused as to how I should call it.

My initial thought is I should make the first axios call to get a list of Pokemon and their detail URL. Once the promise resolves, I would make an array of `axios.get` promises, so something like this:

```
const [characters, setCharacters] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect( () => {
    // make axios call for list of pokemon

    axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
      .then( result => {
        const pokemonUrls = [];
        result.data.results.forEach( character =>
          pokemonUrls.push(character.url)
        )
      })
      .catch( error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);
```

I'm a little confused on what I would do next. Would I call `Promise.all(pokemonUrls)` in that initial `.then()` block? Or do I need to create a new side effect hook?

Any direction so I can know what direction to take next would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course after hours of working on this, as soon as I post the question I figured it out.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
const [characters, setCharacters] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect( () => {
    let characterUrls = [];
    // make axios call for list of pokemon
    axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
      .then( result => {
        return axios.all(result.data.results.map( character => {
          return axios.get(character.url);
        }))
      })
      .then( results => {
        return results.map( character => character.data);
      })
      .then( results => setCharacters(results))
      .catch( error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: I know this is out of the scope of the question but the same seems to able to be accomplished with the fetch browser api.

Comment: I believe you are correct. I have only ever used axios, but I should probably read up on fetch so I could eliminate a 3rd-party dependency. I appreciate the push to do that!

Comment: What is the `characterUrls` used for?

Comment: characterUrls is an array of URLs that have more detail about each Pokémon. 

It’s something like https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1 which would be Bulbasaur